# Components will not load inside of another component's template

Tags: angular

I am using RC5 and for some reason no matter what I do, I cannot get one of my components to load from within the template of another component. I have all of my components included in my app.module.ts and they are all in my declarations of @NgModule. I have my  element inside of app.html which is loading in 3 other components fine based on the url. But if I try to have another component inside of the one that loaded from the router, if I inspect it just shows the html that I put in the template instead of loading the other component. I have spent the last maybe 15 hours trying to figure this out, and I see no reason why it isn't working. Please help.

Here is my app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { routing, appRoutingProviders } from './app.routing';
import {Home} from './home.component';
import {Login} from './login.component';
import {Rating} from './rating.component';
import {Profile} from './profile.component';
import {Subordinates} from './subordinates.component';
import {RateEmployee} from './rate-employee.component';
import {LocalStorageService, LOCAL_STORAGE_SERVICE_CONFIG} from 'angular-2-local-storage';

let localStorageServiceConfig = {
    prefix: 'my-app',
    storageType: 'sessionStorage'
};

@NgModule({
  imports:      [
    BrowserModule,
    routing
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    Home,
    Login,
    Rating,
    Profile,
    Subordinates,
    RateEmployee
  ],
  providers: [
    appRoutingProviders,
    LocalStorageService,
    { provide: LOCAL_STORAGE_SERVICE_CONFIG, useValue: localStorageServiceConfig }
  ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is my app.html

```
<header id="framework-header">
  <!--<div id="logo"><span class="icon-star"></span> Ranky</div>-->
  <div id="logo"><img src="images/logo.svg" alt="Ranky"></div>
  <!--<div id="mobile-menu-buttton"><a href="#menu"><span class="icon-th-menu"></span></a></div>-->


  <nav id="framework-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a routerLink="/profile" routerLinkActive="active">Profile</a></li>
      <li><a routerLink="/subordinates" routerLinkActive="active">Subordinates</a></li>
      <li><a routerLink="/login" routerLinkActive="active">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</header>

<section id="main">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</section>

<footer id="framework-footer">
  <small>&copy; Ranky 2016, All Rights Reserved.</small>
</footer>
```

then profile.html

```
<h2>My Self Ranking</h2>

          <rating></rating>

          <div class="form-row field">
            <label for="confirm-password">Provide self evaluation</label>
            <textarea name="self-comments" id="self-comments"></textarea>
          </div>
```

rating.component.ts

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'rating',
  templateUrl: 'templates/rating.html',
})

export class Rating {}
```

and finally rating.html

```
<div class="label">Click on a star to rank your performance:</div>
```

Comment: Can you replicate the problem on plunker?

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be related to using Gulp-Uglify in my Gulp process for bundling with SystemJS. Apparently that makes things not work and gives no errors...